Can't get Statsforecast plot feature to display inside for loop
I don't seem to be able to get the statsforecast.StatsForecast.plot method to display inside for loops. A bug report may be more appropriate but this seems so basic (and I have seen similar code work elsewhere) that I believe I am missing something. There is a similar question here, but I believe the answer is not really acceptable. The goal is to visualise the cross_validation output from neuralforecast models (such as AutoNHITS), such as was done here with the cutoffs in step 5.
The following is a small reproducible example. The counter var has no impact on the dataframe and the method call works perfectly fine when outside the single iteration for loop. I also attempted to add plt.show() or similar commands to no avail.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from statsforecast import StatsForecast

times_arr = np.arange(datetime(1985,7,1), datetime(1988,3,27), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime).tolist()
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id': ['a'] * 1000 + ['b'] * 1000,
    'ds': times_arr + times_arr,
    'y': np.random.random(2000)
})

for i in range(1):
    StatsForecast.plot(test_df)


The most concise answers seems to be shown in this issue on the statsforecast repo, by jmoralez
from IPython.display import display

for cutoff in cv_df['cutoff'].unique():
    fig = StatsForecast.plot(
        Y_df, 
        cv_df.query('cutoff == @cutoff').drop(columns=['y', 'cutoff']), 
        max_insample_length=48 * 4, 
        unique_ids=['H105'],
        engine='matplotlib'
    )
    display(fig)


Dnk, tried running the code from the terminal, but it didn't work: the graphs immediately disappear after rendering.

Good to know. It worked perfectly in jupyter notebook, which was the goal for me. Given you also complained about a 'vanilla' run of statsforecast on another answer, that appears to be a problem with your setup.

Use my snippet to accomplish your task. The issue is in the StatsForecast.plot which if using matplotlib engine will close the figure gui before returning the figure object. Thus you need to create a new gui and reopen closed figure in the new matplotlib canvas:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from io import BytesIO


times_arr = np.arange(datetime(1985,7,1), datetime(1988,3,27), timedelta(days=1)).astype(datetime).tolist()
test_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id': ['a'] * 1000 + ['b'] * 1000,
    'ds': times_arr + times_arr,
    'y': np.random.random(2000)
})


for i in range(2):
    # the returned figure object is closed
    fig = StatsForecast.plot(test_df)

    # snippet that will reopen closed figure
    new_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,4))
    new_manager = new_fig.canvas.manager
    new_manager.canvas.figure = fig
    fig.set_canvas(new_manager.canvas)

    # wait for user interactions
    plt.show()




You do not need a for loop to plot the results of cross-validation. The dataframe returned by cross-validation already has the associated timestamp, predicted values, and actual values, so you can simply plot it directly.
Here is a minimal working example. I only used two series from the hourly M4 dataset, and trained a NHITS and N-BEATS for a few steps. The models are not optimized for the best performance. Of course, you can change the models for anything you want, like AutoNHITS, etc.
import pandas as pd    
from statsforecast import StatsForecast
from neuralforecast import NeuralForecast
from neuralforecast.models import NHITS, NBEATS

# Read the data and select two series only
Y_df = pd.read_parquet('https://datasets-nixtla.s3.amazonaws.com/m4-hourly.parquet')
uids = Y_df['unique_id'].unique()[:2]
Y_df = Y_df.query('unique_id in @uids').reset_index(drop=True)

# Create an instance of Neuralforecast with models
nf = NeuralForecast(
    models=[
        NHITS(h=48, input_size=96, max_steps=500),
        NBEATS(h=48, input_size=96, max_steps=500),
    ],
    freq=1
)

# Run cross-validation
cv_df = nf.cross_validation(Y_df, n_windows=2)

# Plot the results of cross-validation
StatsForecast.plot(
    Y_df, 
    cv_df.drop(columns=['y', 'cutoff']), 
    max_insample_length=48 * 4, 
    engine='matplotlib'
)


Plot instantly dissapears if I try to run the code in the terminal and thus doesn't solve the problem.
